# Did Joseph Smith go to heaven according to Protestant Trinitarians?

Tags: protestantism, soteriology, lds, heaven, assurance-of-salvation

According to the doctrine of salvation written by Bruce McConkie,

"If it had not been for Joseph Smith and the restoration, there would be no salvation. There is no salvation outside The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints."

[Official Mormon Doctrine](https://archive.org/details/MormonDoctrine1966/page/472/mode/2up)

But Paul says: "...Believe in the Lord Jesus, and you will be saved..."
(Acts 16:31)

Is it mutually exclusive? Could Joseph Smith have gone to heaven according to the NT, obviously extending to all members of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints?

Protestant tradition may used as the starting point of the answer, although biblical support would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No! I'm already way ahead of those that are going to challenge me on this by asking, "How do you know?" According to Joseph's Smith's first vision he stated that God the Father and the Son appeared to him. The first problem is the fact that God the Father cannot be seen with the literal eyes and this is according to Jesus Christ Himself at John 5:37 and at John 6:46.

Point number two is that Smith ask God the Father and His Son which church should I join? Smith was given the answer "that I must join none of them, for they were all wrong; and the personage who addressed me said that all their creeds were an abomination in his sight." The problem with Smith's question is that he was not seeking salvation, which was a foolish question, that is, "what sect is right that he might join it." You do not join a church to get salvation. Salvation only comes by having a personal relationship with Jesus Christ/God This is brought out at John 14:23, "If anyone loves Me, he will keep My word and My Father will love him, and WE will come to him, AND MAKE OUR ABODE WITH HIM." Also read Revelation 3:20.

Problem number three as it pertains to Bruce McConkie. I was told by Hold To The Rod the following: "Mormon Doctrine is not an official church source, and Brother McConkie was severely scolded for including his opinions in it without adequately acknowledge that these were his opinions."

Since these are Mr. McConkie's opinions when he stated the following: "If it had not been for Joseph Smith and the restoration, there would be no salvation. There is no salvation outside The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints." This means to me that his opinions should not count because they are flat out not Biblical.

So I have a question? How did people obtain salvation not only before Joseph Smith showed up, but after he showed up? In any event, Mr. McConkie is "delusional" in my opinion and so is Joseph Smith, they are not to be trusted or believed.

Comment: Can you link to any official Protestant sources that support your opinion ?